# How to put or send my method from my activity to another class to call it?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Here's The idea I'm trying to do in my app:

`MainActivity` got a method with `getServer()` name. now I'm using another class with (Dialogs) name. when app can't reach the server i use this dialog to Activity to let people to try again if problem is fixed. now i created a class with Dialogs and I'm using it as a reference, the problem is i can pass context or other things, but i don't know if it's possible to pass method to dialog to open it.

I'm not trying to call method in class, in this case i should create class for every dialog i build to call method in activity. i want to use one dialog class, and send method to it to call it when user hit yes button.

mPresenter:

```
>well there's not anything about presenter, just a simple call with retrofit
=> if response was ok, then show data(view)
=> throw or error => open Dialog(view) => this method call Dialog.Java class and ask it to call getServer() method.
```

MainActivity:

```
> i want to pass getServer to Dialog.class
public void getServer() {
    mPresenter.setupServer();
}
```

Dialog Class:

```
    public static void RefreshDialog(final Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("run again?");
    builder.setMessage("there's a problem with your connection or our server, wanna try again?");

    builder.setNegativeButton("yes, please.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            > want to dialog call method that received and open it if i've got yes,please!

        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("nah", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do.

a) Create an interface and make your activity implement that interface

The interface should hace a method (onRetryClick(); for example) and the activity should implement this method, and inside that method call your getServer().

Interface:

```
interface Listener {
  onRetryClick();
}
```

Activity:

```
class MyActivity implements Listener {
  ...
  @Override
  public onRetryClick() {
    getServer();
  }
}
```

When calling the dialog pass the activity as a param, and the dialog should be able to receive a Listener object in the params

```
public showErrorDialog(final Listener listener) {...}
```

b) You can create the same listener, and in the activity create an instance of that listener an explicitly define the method

```
class MyActivity {
  ...
  private Listener listener = new Listener() {
    @Override
    public onRetryClick() {
      getServer();
    }
  }
}
```

And pass the listener to the dialog the same way as solution a

I believe b is better because you create a simple Listener object and pass it around, instead of passing the whole implemented activity.

There are more solutions than these ones, if this doesn't help try looking for an EventBus pattern for example.

Comment: i'm trying to work on it, another problem is alert dial using context, which i was providing it from activity dialogs.method(this)...

Comment: Im sorry, I didn't understand the other problem, can you explain it more?

Comment: no problem, fixed it. thanks for answer. working well for now.